# iOS7: UITapGestureRecognizer reuse issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I set three buttons. Every button is tagged 1...3.

[image]

My UITapGestureRecognizer works only once and only for first UIButton. Can't select other two options.
Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [_btnNegative addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [_btnNeutral addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [_btnPositive addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

And the `buttonTapped:` method:

```
-(void)buttonTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    switch (((UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer).view.tag)
    {
         case 1:
        {
            NSLog(@"Positive");
            [_btnPositive setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [_btnNegative setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UncheckedBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [_btnNeutral setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UncheckedBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            _opinion=@"Positive";
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            NSLog(@"Negative");
            [_btnNegative setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [_btnPositive setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UncheckedBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [_btnNeutral setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UncheckedBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            _opinion=@"Negative";
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            NSLog(@"Neutral");
            [_btnNeutral setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [_btnNegative setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UncheckedBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [_btnPositive setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UncheckedBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            _opinion=@"Neutral";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Only `case:1` works. Other cases never get called. I rechecked the button tags and are ok 1...3. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem
Try to assign a new UITapGestureRecognizer to each button:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self      action:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
recognizer.delegate = self;
recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[_btnNegative addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

 recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self      action:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
[_btnNeutral addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

 recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self      action:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
[_btnPositive addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Comment: This is for sure will work. My question is actually if I can reuse the same gesture recognizer. Am sure there's some way.

Comment: I'm quite sure you can't - the gestures refer to the view and it's subview. Moreover, what will you gain by adding the same gesture?
It will call to the same target and action this way too.

Comment: Yes Gal. Sounds right. One pointer can't point to more than object.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Gal. Your answer is complete. I appreciate it much.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't reuse the same gesture recognizer. A gesture recognizer is designed to be attached to one and only one view.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Can you show me more elegant way to alloc and init two additional recognizers or the code Gal Marom has introduced is the maximum elegant?

Comment: create array of the buttons, call a method that loop over the array and add a new gesture to it

Comment: Assuming that all the gesture recognizers are configured the same way, Gai's solution is good.