# How can we assign UITapGestureRecognizer to another view?

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, floating-action-button, uitapgesturerecognizer

I use this library for showcase;

https://github.com/scihant/ctshowcase
While displaying a showcase, it sends a view and throws it into the targetView.
I want to add the GestureRecognizer, which has been added to the view I sent, to the targetView. How can I do this? I tried something like this;

```
public func setup(for view: UIView, offset: CGPoint, margin: CGFloat) {
    guard willShow == true else {return}

    targetView = view
    targetOffset = offset
    targetMargin = margin



    guard let targetView = targetView else {return}

    if let recognizer  = view.gestureRecognizers?.first as? UITapGestureRecognizer{
        targetView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        targetView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    }
    ... 
}
```

but it is not working. Am I technically making a mistake? Is this not possible?

```
func creatFabButton() {
    fabButton = KCFloatingActionButton()
    fabButton.buttonColor = Util.getColor(Colors.red1)
    fabButton.plusColor = UIColor.white
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:   #selector(fabPresed(_:)))
    fabButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    view.addSubview(fabButton)
}

@objc func fabPresed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    let viewController =    NewClientViewController.newViewController(nil)
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    creatFabButton()
}
```

Comment: where you add target to tapReognizer ?

Comment: Within UIView's (view) ViewController @jawadAli

Comment: show that code as well

Comment: func creatFabButton() {
        fabButton = KCFloatingActionButton()
        fabButton.buttonColor = Util.getColor(Colors.red1)
        fabButton.plusColor = UIColor.white
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(fabPresed(_:)))
        fabButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        view.addSubview(fabButton)
    }
    
    @objc func fabPresed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        let viewController = NewClientViewController.newViewController(nil)
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: if let recognizer = view.gestureRecognizers? .first as? uıtapgesturerecogniz is {
.. the recognizer here does not come nil comes full but when i say addGestureRecognizer it doesn't do what I want @jawadAli

Comment: please add code i question .. so that it become readable for others too

Comment: I added @jawadAli

Comment: please specify your controller too .. where you are adding KCFloatingActionButton and its selector

Comment: @jawadAli I'm adding in viewDidLoad with creatFabButton function

Comment: add fabButton.userInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: I did but not worked @jawadAli

Comment: can you share the project ? so that i can figure out whats wrong

Comment: can you give your e-mail address ? @jawadAli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214224/discussion-between-jawadali-and-user9413194).

Answer (score 0):

Gesture recognizers are not reusable. They are designed to be attached to one view only. The solution is to create a dedicated gesture recognizer for each view.

See also this post: [iOS7: UITapGestureRecognizer reuse issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245814/ios7-uitapgesturerecognizer-reuse-issue)

Comment: What does dedicated gesture recognizer mean? 

Do I need to define gesture recognizer from the beginning for the view?

Comment: It means that you have to create a separate gesture recognizer instance for every single view. Have a look at the link I pasted above.